# Retrieve `command line` of a process from its memory dump

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, memory

Can we read the `command line` string of a process from its memory dump?

My motivation is that I want to know what initiated an instance of Windows Command Processor that keeps popping on my screen. The process usually flashes, but sometimes it hangs longer, and I managed to create a memory dump. I wonder if it is possible to know what trigger the process to run from the memory dump.

I have used a hex editor to view the memory dump, but I am not sure what I should be looking for to know what script/programme was running.

Thanks to Niayesh for reminding me that I can find this information in the `command line` column in the task manager. Unfortunately, the pop ups are sporadic, and I might not have a pop up that hangs long enough to open the task manager and read the info for days.

My question is,

> can we find the `command line` information the task manger view for a process in its memory dump? If yes, how can we do that?

PS I am not asking why the cmd window is popping up.

Comment: If you can look at Task Manager while the process is still running, Task Manager has a way to display the command line that produced each process. (It's a column you can add beside CPU, memory, status, etc.)

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to retrieve that information. I'm not sure what kind of memory dump you got but you could try a Dump analyzer to see if you can identify the region in the dump. http://home.hccnet.nl/h.dalmolen/En/Computer/Dump-analysis.htm#commands You could try WinDbg (free in the Windows store), open the dump and use `.tlist -v cmd.exe` (or whatever). It will give you the commandlines (with parameters). There are other commands to get to the complete Process Environment Block (PEB) which contains the actual complete commandline.